# Toggling the opacity of large number of elements with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a huge form that requires me to initially show the opacity of elements at 0.5 and when a button is clicked the opacity is 1.0. I am able to do this with JavaScript but I need to manage it better by not calling an if statement for each element. Note that the elements are in no particular order and some need to toggle the opacity of more than one element.

[Working Demo need to revise](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/ZTUj5/)

SIMPLE CSS

```
 [id^="dp"] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML

```
GROUP 1<BR>
    <input type="radio" id="abc1" name="abc1"  onclick="showabc();"/>
    <label for="abc1"> Yes </label>
    <input type="radio" id="abc2" name="abc1"  onclick="showabc();"/>
    <label for="abc2"> No </label>
    <div id="dpabc1">
    <H4>Content 1 is dimmed</H4>
    </div>

    GROUP 2<BR>
    <input type="radio" id="abc3" name="abc2"  onclick="showabc();"/>
    <label for="abc3"> Yes </label>
    <input type="radio" id="abc4" name="abc2"  onclick="showabc();"/>
    <label for="abc4"> No </label>
    <div id="dpabc7">
    <H4>Content 2 is dimmed</H4>
    </div>

    GROUP 3<BR>
    <input type="radio" id="abc5" name="abc3"  onclick="showabc();"/>
    <label for="abc5"> Yes </label>
    <input type="radio" id="abc6" name="abc3"  onclick="showabc();"/>
    <label for="abc6"> No </label>
    <div id="dpabc9">
    <H4>Content 3 item 1 in its own div</H4>
    </div>
    <div id="dpabc11">
    <H4>Content 3 item2 in its own div</H4>
```

CURRENT JAVASCRIPT I NEED TO REWRITE WITHOUT A BUNCH OF IF STATEMENTS FOR EACH ELEMENT

```
function showabc() {    

        if (document.getElementById("abc1").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("dpabc1").style.opacity = 1.0;
            }

            else {
        document.getElementById("dpabc1").style.opacity = 0.5;  
            }

        if (document.getElementById("abc3").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("dpabc7").style.opacity = 1.0;
            }

            else {
        document.getElementById("dpabc7").style.opacity = 0.5;  
            }

        if (document.getElementById("abc5").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("dpabc9").style.opacity = 1.0;
        document.getElementById("dpabc11").style.opacity = 1.0;
            }

            else {
        document.getElementById("dpabc9").style.opacity = 0.5;
        document.getElementById("dpabc11").style.opacity = 0.5; 
            }       
        }
```

BEGINNING OF CODE REVISION HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCK. What I'm trying to do is match the variables in "checkMe" with the variables in dimMe. You can see abc1 & 3 need to show the opacity change of one item where abc5 needs to change to opacity to two items (dpabc9 & dpabc11).

```
function showabc() {
    var checkMe = ["abc1" , "abc3" , "abc5" ];
    var dimMe = ["dpabc1" , "dpabc7" , "dpabc9, dpabc11"];

        for (var i=0, l=checkMe.length; i<l; ++i) {
            document.getElementById(checkMe[i]).style.opacity = 1.0;
            }

            else {

            document.getElementById(checkMe[i]).style.opacity = 0.5;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can the HTML be amended for simplicity?

Comment: Can it be done without fieldsets and using values? Won't be using fieldsets in my layout and values will be reserved for something else. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Given some minor changes to the HTML, the appropriate grouping of elements within `<fieldset>` elements, and the use of `yes`/`no` values, I'd suggest the following JavaScript:

```
function opacityToggle(){
    // 'this' refers to the element to which the event-handling was bound:
    var divs = this.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    // using CSS syntax offered by 'querySelector()' to find the
    // first input element of 'type=radio' and is checked:
        confirmed = this.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    // iterates over the 'div' elements, and sets the opacity according
    // to whether the checked radio input has the value of 'yes':
    for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
        divs[i].style.opacity = confirmed.value === 'yes' ? 1 : 0.5;
    }
}

// gets the fieldset elements:
var fieldsets = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');

// iterates over the fieldset elements:
for (var i = 0, len = fieldsets.length; i < len; i++) {
    // and uses 'addEventListener' to add a listener for the 'change' event,
    // when that event is detected, the opacityToggle function is called:
    fieldsets[i].addEventListener('change', opacityToggle);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZTUj5/3/).

This works on the following HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>GROUP 1</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="abc1" name="abc1" value="yes" />
    <label for="abc1">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="abc2" name="abc1" value="no" />
    <label for="abc2">No</label>
    <div id="dpabc1">
       <H4>Content 1 is dimmed</H4>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>GROUP 2</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="abc3" name="abc2" value="yes" />
    <label for="abc3"> Yes </label>
    <input type="radio" id="abc4" name="abc2" value="no" />
    <label for="abc4"> No </label>
    <div id="dpabc7">
        <H4>Content 2 is dimmed</H4>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>GROUP 3</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="abc5" name="abc3" value="yes" />
    <label for="abc5"> Yes </label>
    <input type="radio" id="abc6" name="abc3" value="no" />
    <label for="abc6"> No </label>
    <div id="dpabc9">
        <H4>Content 3 item 1 in its own div</H4>
    </div>
    <div id="dpabc11">
        <H4>Content 3 item2 in its own div</H4>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED HTML

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTUj5/7/)

```
GROUP 1<BR>
<input type="radio" id="abc1" name="abc1"  onclick="showabc('content1',1);"/>
<label for="abc1"> Yes </label>

<input type="radio" id="abc2" name="abc1" 
onclick="showabc('content1',0);"/>
<label for="abc2"> No </label>

<div id="dpabc1" class="content1">
<H4>Content 1 is dimmed</H4>
</div>

GROUP 2<BR>
<input type="radio" id="abc3" name="abc2"  onclick="showabc('content2',1);"/>
<label for="abc3"> Yes </label>
<input type="radio" id="abc4" name="abc2"  onclick="showabc('content2',0);"/>
<label for="abc4"> No </label>
<div id="dpabc7" class="content2">
<H4>Content 2 is dimmed</H4>
</div>

GROUP 3<BR>
<input type="radio" id="abc5" name="abc3"  onclick="showabc('content3',1);"/>
<label for="abc5"> Yes </label>
<input type="radio" id="abc6" name="abc3"  onclick="showabc('content3',0);"/>
<label for="abc6"> No </label>
<div id="dpabc9" class="content3">
<H4>Content 3 item 1 in its own div</H4>
</div>
<div id="dpabc11" class="content3">
<H4>Content 3 item2 in its own div</H4>
</div>
```

UPDATED JAVASCRIPT

```
function showabc(cssClass,makeBold) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cssClass);
    var opacity = 1.0;
    if (makeBold == 0) {
        opacity = 0.5;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.opacity = opacity;
    }
  }
```